# Plotting live pie-chart using matplotlib pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
for i in range(100):
    plt.pie([100-i,i])
    sleep(1)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Problem with my code:

- Whenever the values of plt.pie() changes and the pie chart are plotted then execution of for loop seems to be halted and I have to close the pie chart window to resume to the execution of for loop.

What I want to do:

- plt.pie() display live changes in its values without halting for loop's execution.

thank you.

Comment: Please have a look at [matplotlib animations](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#animation), which are especially created to be able to run code *inside* the event loop and to hence avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
for i in range(100):
   plt.pie([100-i, i])
   plt.pause(.001)
   plt.draw()
   sleep(1)
```

`plt.show()` is blocking function so instead used `plt.draw()` along with `plt.pause()` and now it's working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

add `plt.close()` to your for-loop

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
for i in range(100):
    plt.pie([100-i,i])
    sleep(1)
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

Comment: This is not working.
plt.show() seems to be blocking the execution of plt.close() function too.

Comment: what if you remove plt.show() and add plt.figure() as the first line in your for loop?

Comment: I used plt.draw() with plt.pause() and it is working now. plt.draw() is a non-blocking function so it does not halts the execution of the loop.